# Separate working directories between appdomains

Tags: appdomain, working-directory

I have a .NET application that is creating several separate AppDomains to run some plugginable code, each of the AppDomains sets up its own WCF named pipes service to communicate with the central application.

However I want to set a different working directory for each AppDomain, so that the base folder of any relative path is different in each app domain. So these plugins can create its own folder structure in all the normal file handling ways by going "./MyCustomFolder".

Unfortunately I am finding Directory.SetWorkingDirectory() is setting it for the whole process (not isolated to a single app domain) this is causing some plugins to write in other plugin directories.

Is it possible to change the working directory for different AppDomains, or do I need to kick off brand new processes to do what I'm after? If I need whole processes to do what Im after what is your opinions on trying to manage parent / child processes effectively in a stable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CurrentDirectory (or WorkingDirectory) is per process.

You can however setup assembly probing paths when creating the appdomain. Look at the [AppDomainSetup](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup) class.

Comment: Its not just assemblies that are being loaded from a relative directory, but general resources as well (images, txt, csv, etc)

Comment: @Alex: I suspected that after I wrote the answer. Not sure what I can suggest. It highly depends on how and when things are loaded.

Comment: The plugins are created at startup but access resources throughout their operation. They do exist on a long running service so there would not be much overhead in creating them as processes, just issues in managing the additional processes on fatal errors and such

Comment: Marked as answer, as i was looking for confirmation that there was no other way to do this before i start evaluating the work needed to create new processes. Thanks leppie